# What is the policy with stale unanswered questions that have become irrelevant?

Tags: discussion, questions, closing-questions

While going through the unanswered questions, I cam across this question "https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14784/does-indias-national-spot-exchange-support-web-based-trading-for-retail-investo"

The National Spot Exchange has since gone bankrupt [August 2013] and hence the question is irrelevant. How should we go about this and other such question that may have answers but the questions themselves are irrelevant.

Answer (score 8):

In the scenario where the question is *unanswered*, I suggest the following:

- Add a comment explaining why the question is obsolete. Include a supporting reference.
- Flag the question for moderator attention.

Once we confirm the unanswered question is now irrelevant, we can:

- Close the question, and
- Delete it, eventually.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to actually consider leaving the question for historical purposes.

While an individual implementation (e.g. a particular spot market) may have been wound down, there may be an historical precedent or principle in the answer that is still relevant.

I agree that the question should be updated to reflect the situation - but the principles and the precedents in good answers still provide value.

Comment: +1 and aha -- I just realized I only addressed the *unanswered* question scenario in my own answer.  I agree that we shouldn't delete questions that have answers with value.

Comment: I think even questions without answers may have value too. They are often epistemological "indicators" as to what has been asked before, what the availability of answers are (_e.g._ sparse or none), and perhaps the question may even contain links and/or ideas that an asker of a related question may not have thought to check. (My opinion is not strong however; I can also argue for their deletion. Just adding another perspective.)

Comment: Agreed, you may need to understand the past to understand the present.